# Converting a dataframe to a nested Json output

Tags: json, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe which is derived from data, which gives me something like this

| id | identifier | actual_cost | cost_incurred | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc123 | 24 | 21 | 2021-04-16T19:07:00 |
| 2 | xyz987 | 12 | 34 | 2021-04-16T19:25:27 |
| 2 | xyz987 | 92 | 87 | 2021-04-16T19:32:43 |
| 1 | abc123 | 37 | 39 | 2021-04-16T19:26:30 |
| 3 | abc567 | 87 | 85 | 2021-04-16T19:13:00 |

My requirement being the final dump file should have the whole data frame as a nested JSON like this

```
 {
"hits": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "identifier": "abc123",
        "cost": [
            {
                "actual_cost": 24,
                "cost_incurred": 21,
                "timestamp": "2021-04-16T19:07:00"
            },
            {
                "actual_cost": 37,
                "cost_incurred": 39,
                "timestamp": "2021-04-16T19:26:30"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "identifier": "xyz987",
        "cost": [
            {
                "actual_cost": 12,
                "cost_incurred": 34,
                "timestamp": "2021-04-16T19:25:27"
            },
            {
                "actual_cost": 37,
                "cost_incurred": 39,
                "timestamp": "2021-04-16T19:26:30"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "identifier": "abc567",
        "cost": [
            {
                "actual_cost": 87,
                "cost_incurred": 85,
                "timestamp": "2021-04-16T19:13:00"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

I was looking at the map function but couldn't figure out the way to group the result.
Any leads or solution will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`to_json` will be your friend :) and some grouping and aggregation:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")

result = spark.sql("""
    select 
        to_json(struct(collect_list(item) hits)) result 
    from (
        select 
            struct(
                id, identifier, collect_list(struct(actual_cost, cost_incurred, timestamp)) cost
            ) item 
        from df 
        group by id, identifier
    )
""")

result.show()
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|result                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"hits":[{"id":"2","identifier":"xyz987","cost":[{"actual_cost":"12","cost_incurred":"34","timestamp":"2021-04-16T19:25:27"},{"actual_cost":"92","cost_incurred":"87","timestamp":"2021-04-16T19:32:43"}]},{"id":"1","identifier":"abc123","cost":[{"actual_cost":"24","cost_incurred":"21","timestamp":"2021-04-16T19:07:00"},{"actual_cost":"37","cost_incurred":"39","timestamp":"2021-04-16T19:26:30"}]},{"id":"3","identifier":"abc567","cost":[{"actual_cost":"87","cost_incurred":"85","timestamp":"2021-04-16T19:13:00"}]}]}|
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it with groupBy some aggregration and toJSON

```
val resultDf = df.groupBy("id", "identifier")
  .agg(collect_list(struct("actual_cost", "cost_incurred", "timestamp")) as "cost")
  .toJSON
resultDf.show(false)
```

Result:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|value                                                                                                                                                                                  |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"id":2,"identifier":"xyz987","cost":[{"actual_cost":12,"cost_incurred":34,"timestamp":"2021-04-16T19:25:27"},{"actual_cost":92,"cost_incurred":87,"timestamp":"2021-04-16T19:32:43"}]}|
|{"id":1,"identifier":"abc123","cost":[{"actual_cost":24,"cost_incurred":21,"timestamp":"2021-04-16T19:07:00"},{"actual_cost":37,"cost_incurred":39,"timestamp":"2021-04-16T19:26:30"}]}|
|{"id":3,"identifier":"abc567","cost":[{"actual_cost":87,"cost_incurred":85,"timestamp":"2021-04-16T19:13:00"}]}                                                                        |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

If you want in a single row then

```
result.agg(to_json(collect_list(struct(result.columns.map(col): _*))).as("hits"))
.show(false)
```

Result:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|hits                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[{"id":2,"identifier":"xyz987","cost":[{"actual_cost":12,"cost_incurred":34,"timestamp":"2021-04-16T19:25:27"},{"actual_cost":92,"cost_incurred":87,"timestamp":"2021-04-16T19:32:43"}]},{"id":1,"identifier":"abc123","cost":[{"actual_cost":24,"cost_incurred":21,"timestamp":"2021-04-16T19:07:00"},{"actual_cost":37,"cost_incurred":39,"timestamp":"2021-04-16T19:26:30"}]},{"id":3,"identifier":"abc567","cost":[{"actual_cost":87,"cost_incurred":85,"timestamp":"2021-04-16T19:13:00"}]}]|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```